# Prevent pass by reference in initilializer list

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors

Here an example code that gets me the following error :

```
no matching function for call to 'QGraphicsScene::QGraphicsScene(qreal&, qreal&, qreal, qreal, QGraphicsView*&)'
```

Header :

```
#include <QtGui/qgraphicsscene.h>
#include <QtGui/qgraphicsview.h>

class MyScene : QGraphicsScene
{

public:
    MyScene (QGraphicsView* graphsView, qreal x, qreal y);

    void drawSelf();

};
```

Cpp :

```
#include "MyScene.h"

MyScene::MyScene(QGraphicsView* graphsView, qreal x, qreal y) :
    QGraphicsScene(x, y, (qreal)(100), (qreal)(100), graphsView)
{

}

void MyScene::drawSelf()
{
    /* Draw here using QGraphicsScene methods */
}
```

It seems the initializer list forces stuff to be passed by reference, which the compiler doesn't like somehow. I tried by passing some fixed values to the `QGraphicsScene` constructor, not coming from the constructor, and then it compiled. So it's really only with the data passed to the constructor that it fails.

What should I do ?

Comment: You reached the wrong conclusion I'm afraid. Nothing is forced to be passed by reference because it's in a member initializer list. It's just a compiler error message that's confusing you. One or more of the parameters you pass to the `QGraphicsScene` don't match what it expects. Probably a failed coercion of `QGraphicsView*` to whatever.

Comment: References in the error message just mean that you're passing in l-values.